# Outputting Issue with File Conversion

Tags: c++, html, html-entities

This is a remake of a question I just asked a few minutes ago. Basically I want a line break to be displayed that is one less than the number of new line carriage returns. So if there are three new lines in a row, the line breaks should be two. Is there any way to do this?

```
while( infile.get( ch ) ) 
{
  switch( ch )
  {
    case '\n':
        outfile << "<br />";
        break;
    case '\t':
        outfile << tab;
        break;
    case '&':
        outfile << "&amp;";
        break;
    case '<':
            outfile << "&lt;";
        break;
    case '>':
            outfile << "&gt;";
        break;
    case '"':
            outfile << "&quot;";
        break;
    default:
        outfile << ch;
        break;
 }  

if( ch == '\n' )
 {
   inputLines++;
 }
```

}

Sample output should look like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5a647913f83f796914c

Comment: Yes. Either (a) look at more than 1 char at a time or (b) don't emit the 2nd `<br>` I.e set a flag that says which char was received last and another that says whether or not a `<br>` has been skipped.

Comment: How would I test for your b option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you.  Essentially it skips the first newline detected.  If you have 3 newline input, you'll have 2 line breaks.  Note that if you have only one newline, you'll just get a newline character (not a line break).

```
bool first_nl = true;
while( infile.get( ch ) ) 
{
    switch( ch )
    {
        case '\n':
            if ( first_nl ) {
                outfile << "\n";
                first_nl = false;

            } else {
                outfile << "<br />\n";
            }
            break;

        case '\t':
            outfile << tab;
            break;

        case '&':
            outfile << "&amp;";
            break;

        case '<':
            outfile << "&lt;";
            break;

        case '>':
            outfile << "&gt;";
            break;

        case '"':
            outfile << "&quot;";
            break;

        default:
            outfile << ch;
            break;
    }

    if( ch == '\n' )
    {
        inputLines++;

    } else {
        first_nl = true;
    }
}
```

Using this, you won't have to deal with any "peeking" at the next character.

Comment: Okay, this option gets me much closer than I have been but I am having a few issues. If you look at the output with these changes here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5a82eecaeafc1c51f6d0 I get all the text on one line. I want the line breaks to basically replace new lines and fill in the white space like in the output in my main post. If I add a new line after the line break output, it gets close, but some of the characters are still put on the same line.

Comment: Can you post the input you used? I might be able to do more if I had that.

Comment: Using this as my test file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a40797c68da858e03323

Comment: @AaronG. I've modified my answer.

Comment: I just tested your updated code with my program and it does not add any line breaks to the program upon output.

Comment: Whoops, I put `first_nl = false;` in the wrong section of the `if`.  It's corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you will have to detect that you have "multiple of the same", which means building a statemachine of sorts.

A simple version, to cope only with what you are doing is to have a "peek-buffer";

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int buffer = 0;

int peek(ifstream &infile)
{
   if (buffer) return buffer;
   char ch;
   if (!infile.get( ch ))
       buffer = -1;
   else
       buffer = ch;
   return buffer;
}

int get(ifstream &infile)
{
   int ch = peek(infile);
   buffer = 0;
   cout << "ch = " << ch << endl;
   return ch;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    ofstream outfile(argv[2]);

    int ch;
    while( (ch = get(infile)) != -1 ) 
    {
        int count = 0;
        switch( ch )
        {
        case '\n':
            while (peek(infile) == '\n')
            {
                count ++;
                get(infile);
            }
            count--;  // One less. 
            if (count <= 0) count = 1;    // Assuming we want one output if there is only one. 
            for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                outfile << "<br />";
            }
            break;
        default:
            outfile << (char)ch;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there are other clever ways to do this.

Comment: When I ran this, I got an infinite loop. How are you supposed to implement this properly?

Comment: I am getting an error that says, get should return a value and a warning that in the peek method that not all control paths return a value. Is the get method supposed to return ch?

Comment: I've just updated to a complete program that runs and (in my understanding of the task) does the right thing. There were a couple of typos in the original code.